# Script to save files from Mac (iCloud) to S3 bucket (AWS)

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, icloud

So i guess first we need to write a script to save all the files from my iCloud which I guess we would have to do an API call for that? Then backup those files onto my aws S3 bucket. Then the next question is, do I have to manually run the script or can we automate the runtime of the script to go off every hour.

Thanks!

Comment: Amazon S3 cannot "pull" content, so you would need a script running 'somewhere' that will retrieve the content from iCloud and upload to S3. You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command. However, can you possibly **edit your question** to tell us more about your actual use-case? For example: Are the files on a Mac, or are they in iCloud. How does it know _which_ files to copy? How often do you want to sync the files? _Why_ do you want to sync the files -- for processing, or just for backup? Why not just use Dropbox? More info, please!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind, you can use a python script to do a combination of the ff:

1. `pyicloud` - To interact with your iCloud services and download your files locally.

```py
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService

api = PyiCloudService('jappleseed@apple.com', 'password')

# Some more setup if you have two-factor (or two-step) authentication

api.files.dir()

# Download the files you want locally, you can also open up a file stream if needed
```

2. `boto3` - To interact with S3 service configured in your AWS account and upload (or backup) the files to your bucket.

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
)

# Loop over your local files to back them up to S3

response = client.upload_file(local_filename, bucket_name, s3_filename)
```

3. Finally, you can setup some `cron job` to schedule your script to run daily if you want to be the one to manage the box where it will run. An alternative here is to build a more Cloud-native solution which is to place your entire python code on a `Lambda function` that will be triggered by `CloudWatch event` which will be scheduled daily.